# put user variables in SUB command UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

I have this code :

```
awk -v antik1=$1 -v antik2=$2 '{ sub(/antik1/,"$antik2") ; print }' persons.dat.txt
echo " $1 , $2 "
```

where i give the $1 and $2 with this command :

```
./tool.sh  Yang replacement
```

The persons.dat.txt file is this :

```
> 16492674422392|Alberto|Parra|female|1985-09-22|2012-09-01T01:30:59.228+0000|190.96.12.239|Chrome
> 16492674424948|Peng|Chen|female|1984-07-26|2012-09-23T00:51:52.900+0000|1.4.10.198|Internet
> Explorer
> 16492674425075|Changpeng|Xu|female|1984-03-27|2012-10-02T03:55:00.946+0000|1.50.15.119|Firefox
> 16492674425398|Prince|Kobayashi|male|1989-08-07|2012-09-30T03:30:41.772+0000|14.101.89.18|Chrome
> 16492674426410|Yang|Wei|male|1980-07-01|2012-10-01T13:11:48.528+0000|27.144.204.193|Firefox
```

But when i executed it does not replace 'Yang' with 'replacement' . SO, my problem is , how can i insert varibles $1 and $2 to sub ? Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: remove the `$` in front of `$antik2` in first line.

Comment: nothing happens... it doesnt get the Yang from /antik1/ ...

Comment: just use this simple sed command: `sed -r 's/\b'"$1"'\b/'"$2"'/g' persons.dat.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v antik1=$1 -v antik2=$2 '
{   
    sub(antik1, antik2);
    print;
}' persons.dat.txt
```

Run command:

```
$ ./tool.sh Yang replacement
```

**Output:**

```
> 16492674422392|Alberto|Parra|female|1985-09-22|2012-09-01T01:30:59.228+0000|190.96.12.239|Chrome
> 16492674424948|Peng|Chen|female|1984-07-26|2012-09-23T00:51:52.900+0000|1.4.10.198|Internet
> Explorer
> 16492674425075|Changpeng|Xu|female|1984-03-27|2012-10-02T03:55:00.946+0000|1.50.15.119|Firefox
> 16492674425398|Prince|Kobayashi|male|1989-08-07|2012-09-30T03:30:41.772+0000|14.101.89.18|Chrome
> 16492674426410|replacement|Wei|male|1980-07-01|2012-10-01T13:11:48.528+0000|27.144.204.193|Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ in front of $antik2 in first line, and remove more control characters

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v antik1=$1 -v antik2=$2 '
    { r=$0; }   # set a default row value
antik1  { sub(antik1,antik2,r); }  # replace if antik1 matches
    { print r; } # print all lines.
END { print "replaced \""antik1"\" with \""antik2"\"."; } # print the arguments.
' person.txt
```

#### TEST OUTPUT

```
$ bash change_person.sh Y'.*'g test
16492674422392|Alberto|Parra|female|1985-09-22|2012-09-01T01:30:59.228+0000|190.96.12.239|Chrome
16492674424948|Peng|Chen|female|1984-07-26|2012-09-23T00:51:52.900+0000|1.4.10.198|Internet
Explorer
16492674425075|Changpeng|Xu|female|1984-03-27|2012-10-02T03:55:00.946+0000|1.50.15.119|Firefox
16492674425398|Prince|Kobayashi|male|1989-08-07|2012-09-30T03:30:41.772+0000|14.101.89.18|Chrome
16492674426410|test|Wei|male|1980-07-01|2012-10-01T13:11:48.528+0000|27.144.204.193|Firefox
replaced Y.*g with test.
```